# Bundle SQLite Database with android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I need to bundle a static database with my android app which must be replaced every time the app is installed/updated. I don't want it to be replaced at every start of the first activity. Placing the database in Assets doesn't seem to be feasible. Is there any way to do it using AndroidStudio?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a bit of coding:

```
import java.io.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

...

String dbName = /* db name */
Context context = /* read android context from somewhere */
File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath( dbName );
// Test if DB file has been previously deployed.
if( !dbFile.exists() ) {
    // Deploy the DB file.
    AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
    // Open an input stream on the source db file in assets.
    // (Production code will need try/catch/finally around this block)
    InputStream in = assets.open("dbname.sqlite");
    // Open an output stream on the target location.
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( dbFile );
    // Copy the contents. (In actual code you would want to
    // use a buffer).
    int byte;
    while( (byte = in.read()) != -1 ) {
        out.write( byte );
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Placing the database in Assets doesn't seem to be feasible

Sure it is. [Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: The README suggests adding a line in build.gardle , There is two build.gardle files, one for the project and one for the module. Which one should be updated. As far as I guess, it should be the project one. Is it correct?

Comment: @VipulKumar: "Which one should be updated" -- runtime dependencies, like the `SQLiteAssetHelper` library, go in the module's `build.gradle` file. Gradle plugins go in the project's `build.gradle` file.